# Margin:auto; won't work even after width is specified?

Tags: html, css, css-position

this may be a simple question but I can't figure out why this image (id=daftfont) wont center?
Currently I am just trying to center these two images on the page. Margin:auto; worked for the second image just fine, however the first image wont center. I am a beginner so I'm having trouble figuring out why. I appreciate any insight.

```html
    <style>

    body{
     background-color: black;
     }

    #daftfont{
     margin:auto;
     width:170px;
     }

    #daft{
     margin:auto;
     width:200px;
     height:200px;
     border-style:solid;
     border-color:white;
    }

    </style>


     <img id="daftfont" src="https://i.ibb.co/nbFjzX6/daft-punk-transparent.png">
  
     <div id="daft">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/4pFZZc4/Daft-Punk-200x200.jpg">
     </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To center an html element with `margin: auto`, this need to have `display: block`. In the second case the div is block:

Add this rule to your image to center it:

```
#daftfont{
 display: block; /* add this */
 margin:auto;
 width:170px;
}
```

```css
body{
 background-color: black;
 }

#daftfont{
 display: block;
 margin:auto;
 width:170px;
 }

#daft{
 margin:auto;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 border-style:solid;
 border-color:white;
}
```

```html
<img id="daftfont" src="https://i.ibb.co/nbFjzX6/daft-punk-transparent.png">

<div id="daft">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/4pFZZc4/Daft-Punk-200x200.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much, I understand not only how to fix it, but why it didn't work in the first place!

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:block` on `img#daftfont` to make `margin` active.

**Explanation:** `img` by default have `display` as `inline`, however `margin` takes effect for elements with `display` `block`, so you need to change `display` property on `img#daftfont`. In second case `margin` is applied on a  `div` element which by default has `display` `block`, so no problem happens. Another solution is to wrap the `img#daftfont` inside a `div` element and set `margin:auto` to that, like you do in second case.

```html
  <style>

    body{
     background-color: black;
     }

    #daftfont{
     margin:auto;
     width:170px;
     display:block;
     }

    #daft{
     margin:auto;
     width:200px;
     height:200px;
     border-style:solid;
     border-color:white;
    }

    </style>


     <img id="daftfont" src="https://i.ibb.co/nbFjzX6/daft-punk-transparent.png">
  
     <div id="daft">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/4pFZZc4/Daft-Punk-200x200.jpg">
     </div>
```